# MySQL Inner Join not returning correct value

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a question in my query. why I can't filter using a.train_num?. The result is always 0. But when I filter using c.stridnumber then I am getting result.

please check my below query.

```
SELECT a.*,b.*,c.* 
FROM pos_train_db a
INNER JOIN emp_db b
    ON a.pos_name = b.emp_position
INNER JOIN tms_ml c
    ON b.ID = c.stridnumber
WHERE a.train_num=10
```

Comment: There are no matching entries in table `b ` or `c` for `a.train_num=10`. Note that `INNER JOIN` only returns rows, which have a match in both source tables!

Comment: sorry im new to JOIN query. should i rewrite my query to be all the same field? like for example all is looking for ID ? or what JOIN should i use? INNER,LEFT? thanks!

Comment: If you want to have rows in your result set, which only have an entry in `a`, but not in `b` or  `c`, use `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->sql = 
    "SELECT a.*,b.*,c.* FROM pos_train_db a   
    LEFT JOIN emp_db b  ON a.pos_name = b.emp_position
    LEFT JOIN tms_ml c  ON b.ID = c.stridnumber
    WHERE a.train_num=10 ";
```